# Magento indexing is failing, SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: magento-1.7, indexing, sql, reindex

For some reason Magento indexing is failing, we haven't changed anything in the website.... And that is the weird thing! The error in shell using indexer.php:

```
$ php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`**********_db`.`#sql-649_47012`, CONSTRAINT  `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES  `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON U)' in  /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(340): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2569): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(816): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1)
#10 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/shell/indexer.php(160): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /home/**********/domains/***********nna.nl/public_html/shell/indexer.php(200): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

Comment: Check my answer on this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105393/cant-re-index-category-products-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violati/105412#105412 Hope this will help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it seams that you have zombie data in the flat table for store with id 1.
The `prepareFlatTable` method is trying to add a Foreign Key to the `catalog_product_entity` table and that fails.
Most probably because you already have in the `catalog_product_flat_store_1` table a product id that is not in the `catalog_product_entity` table.

First backup your database (or at least `catalog_product_flat_store_1` table), then truncate the table `catalog_product_flat_store_1`.

Or you can disable the usage of the flat catalog, remove the tables `catalog_product_flat_store_*`, re run the indexing then enable the usage of flat tables again.

Comment: i only have a table called `catalog_product_flat_1`, could that be the same?

Comment: yes. I assume you have only one store view in your instance. the `1` at the end is the store view id. Magento creates one flat table for each store view.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for this answer, couldn't find the right one on the interwebs

Answer (score -1):

```
I have 4 languages so i truncated 4 tables.
catalog_product_flat_1, 2,  3, 4
```

EDIT : It seems wrong, do not proceed please.