# Can't re-index Category Products - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: magento-1.9, database, indexing

I'm getting the following error when I try to re-index *Category Products*.  Any way I can repair the database?  I tried the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14594063/1814446) but neither of the queries suggested worked.

I wonder if I truncated the table `catalog_category_product_index` if that would fix things by causing the table data to be re-generate or would just break things further.

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
Category Products index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`local_080316`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity`)' in /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `rr...', Array)
#5 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `rr...', Array)
#6 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `rr...')
#7 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(49): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_cat...', Array, false)
#8 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_cat...', Array, false)
#9 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('catalog_cat...', 'catalog_cat...', false)
#10 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php(935): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#11 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/magento-root/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /var/www/magento-root/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`local_080316`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity`), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) SELECT `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`category_id`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`product_id`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`position`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`is_parent`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`store_id`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`visibility` FROM `catalog_category_product_index_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `position` = VALUES(`position`), `is_parent` = VALUES(`is_parent`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `visibility` = VALUES(`visibility`)' in /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `rr...', Array)
#4 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `rr...', Array)
#5 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `rr...')
#6 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(49): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_cat...', Array, false)
#7 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_cat...', Array, false)
#8 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('catalog_cat...', 'catalog_cat...', false)
#9 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php(935): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#10 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/magento-root/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /var/www/magento-root/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}
```

Comment: May be it will help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51536/magento-indexing-is-failing-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation

Comment: @Arunendra, thanks but that is for the *Catalog Flat Data* index rather than the *Catalog Products* index.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_gallery` WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE product_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE category_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_category_entity); 
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_website` WHERE product_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`); 
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` WHERE entity_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`); 
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` WHERE entity_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`); 
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_link` WHERE product_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`); 
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_relation` WHERE parent_id NOT IN(SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity`);
```

Run this query and then try to reindex

Comment: this worked perfectly for me.  Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Cheers my friend :)

Comment: It worked for me :) nice post, thanks for help